# can you create an instance of an object dynamically in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a blackjack game using Java on console. I'm at the stage where I need to decide how many players will  be participating in each round. Before every round begins, console asks the user to type in how many players will be playing this round and create player object corresponding to that number. The restriction is from 0 to 5. I need to figure out how I'm going to create 1~5 Player objects based on the input. How would you create instance(s) of an object dynamically in java? I know you can do switch statements but was wondering if there is another way.

Comment: How do you use a `switch` statement here? Seems more of a fit for a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute `new Player()` in a loop it will generate as many instances as you execute the loop. In your case the question is most likely not how to actually generate the players, but how to remeber them for later use. You do that by storing them in a collection or array:

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<number;i++) {
    players.add(new Player(i));
}
```

In this case I generate as many players as `number` and will pass the actual number to the constructor of the Player instance.

If you really want to generate instances of different classes (for example all implementing the Player interface) you would have to do this hardcoded (like the switch statement you mentioned) or with reflection. In the later case you need a array/collection of the actual class names or a rule how to generate them. But I really think having all players from the same class is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Creating new object in Java is typically done with the "new" keyword. If you have already defined your Player class, then it would be like this:

```
Player player1 = new Player();
```

In case you want to distinguish between players, you can use for example a "name" property of the class Player. And add methods to set and get that property value. They are called getters and setters:

```
public class Player {

String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Now, let's imagine that the number of player is in variable "numPlayers". We can now create as many players as numPlayers holds. We will use a list to store those players:

```
    ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numPlayers; i++) {
          Player p = new Player();
          p.setName("Player " + i);
          players.add(p);
    }
```

Now your players are in "players" list. To get each player, you can use

```
Player player1 = players.get(0); // get first player
Player player2 = players.get(1); // get second player, etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1; i=>numberOfPlayers; i++; ){
  myListOfPLayers.add(new Player());
}
```